# How do IRC clients, shells and bouncers work?

Tags: shell, irc, irssi

let's say I take free shell and start irssi with the nick: `nick_test` and of course nick stays online 24/7, right?

But if I connect with my IRC client, like mIRC or xchat and set  my nick to `nick_test` I'm not be able connect because the nick will be taken, right? I need a bit infomation.

Comment: When you say "free shell", do you mean a free shell account? Or a shell that is not currently in use?

Comment: Even if a name is taken you'll be able to connect, most clients will automatically pick a guest name, or failing that the ircd will likely do it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstand IRSSI to some extent - IRSSI is merely a CLI IRC client, you access over a remote terminal app. What you're asking for is called a bouncer - effectively a persistent 'proxy' type programme that remains connected to the network, and relays to another IRC client when connected. [psyBNC](http://www.psybnc.at/) is a common one.

I'd note not all IRC networks or shells support psyBNC, and your mileage may vary in terms of performance.

Comment: ZNC is a superior alternative to psyBNC.

Comment: to me, the best bouncer i've used was winbnc, but its impossible to find :(

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @Journetman Geek 's answer, what you are talking about is indeed a bouncer. But even in a free shell that does not provide a bouncer, you can still stay online with your nick even if you are not actually logged into the shell. The trick is to use `screen`.

Start up a `screen` session and start irssi from within it. Then, when you want to log out, don't /quit from irssi but deattach from screen (use `C-a d`) and then logout of the shell. When you login back into the shell again, just start screen to reattach to the running session (use `screen -raAd`). Thus your nick stays online even though you are off the shell.